# GitLab API To Access File Storage?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

In GitLab; Groups and User avatars, Logos are saved as System files.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/file_storage.html

Is there any API available to access them?

**Example Use case**
In a rest response of my app, I got:

`"avatar_url": "http://example.com/uploads/-/system/project/avatar/227/my-logo.jpg",`

But I cannot get this content directly.

Comment: Where do you want to implement it, Android, Web (e.g. PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we don't need an API for that.
I just appended the `private_token` and tried, It Worked!

```
http://example.com/uploads/-/system/project/avatar/227/my-logo.jpg?private_token=9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK
```

Comment: Mark this as the answer, please give us more information on a following question.